# What color palette is cm.colors() in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization

Base R (`grDevices`) comes with several color palette functions, however the documentation for these palettes is poor. I am wondering what palette the `cm.colors()` function maps onto.

For example:

```
plot(x = mtcars[order(mtcars$wt), c("wt", "mpg")],
     col = cm.colors(length(mtcars$wt)),
     pch = 16, cex = 1.25)
```

[image]

Comment: Candy melted, probably :)

Comment: Haha wow. Is that a well known color palette?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Here's mildly educated guess. `cm` is short for color map", (which I understand) by itself is entirely unhelpful.</strike> It's short for cyan-magenta. If you look at the code (which is what used to be the standard response on Rhelp whenever a complaint about skimpy documentation came up) you see that it is really a wrapper for the `hsv` function with particular endpoints for a range of colors which have no variation in the intensities of the "blue".

```
> cm.colors
function (n, alpha, rev = FALSE) 
{
  if ((n <- as.integer(n[1L])) > 0L) {
    even.n <- n%%2L == 0L
    k <- n%/%2L
    l1 <- k + 1L - even.n
    l2 <- n - k + even.n
    cols <- c(if (l1 > 0L) hsv(h = 6/12, 
                               s = seq.int(0.5, 
                                           if (even.n) { 0.5/k} else{ 0}, 
                                           length.out = l1), 
                               v = 1, 
                               alpha = alpha), 
              if (l2 > 1) hsv(h = 10/12,
                              s = seq.int(0, 0.5, length.out = l2)[-1L], 
                              v = 1, alpha = alpha))
    if (rev) 
      rev(cols)
    else cols
  }
  else character()
}
<bytecode: 0x5572a94bc638>
<environment: namespace:grDevices>
> ?hsv

HSV Color Specification
Description
Create a vector of colors from vectors specifying hue, saturation and value.
```

So my hunch was wrong as pointed out below.

```
> cm.colors(2)
[1] "#80FFFF" "#FF80FF"
> col2rgb("cyan")
      [,1]
red      0
green  255
blue   255
> col2rgb("magenta")
      [,1]
red    255
green    0
blue   255
```

And I suspect that the S/R graphics people back in the old days thought we ought to either know what this color specification consisted of or that we would look it up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

Comment: It's short for cyan-magenta.

Comment: @27ϕ9 Really?. What are your sources?

Comment: It's in the documentation - `All of these functions (except the helper function hcl.pals) create a vector of n contiguous colors, either based on the HSV color space (rainbow, heat, terrain, topography, and cyan-magenta colors) or the perceptually-based HCL color space.`

Comment: That makes (in hindsight) *perfect* sense to me, given the context of the `Details:` and the functions included in that one help doc. (I actually started going back through the [R-source](https://github.com/wch/r-source) looking for when `cm.colors` was created, hoping a commit provided some context. I found it was "split from base" in Dec 2003, but could not find the `base/*.R` from which it was split, so could not find its actual origin.)

Comment: Thanks @27ϕ9. I suspect that if I now plug in values to the code I might get values ranging from cyam=n to magenta.